# Why does taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size default to 0 bytes in Flink?

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, apache-flink

Why does this setting default to 0 bytes? In our application, there are dependencies that use direct memory, but we didn't know it before, and then triggered `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory`, so we found that it was caused by insufficient direct memory. Under the current design, if the default settings are used, does it mean that the application can still use the direct memory, but the direct memory pre-allocated to the framework and the network is preempted? Because they share the `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` setting?

Reference: 
[Configuration | Apache Flink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/deployment/config/#taskmanager-memory-task-off-heap-size)
[Set up TaskManager Memory | Apache Flink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/memory/mem_setup_tm/)

Supplementary question: After `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory` occurs, will the previously allocated direct memory be released? Will previously held file descriptors be released?

We found that physical memory will be exhausted after many times `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory`, and sometimes file descriptors will also be exhausted, so I want to know the answer to the above question.